# Ganache, Truffle, Metamask, and Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, metamask, ganache

Can someone please explain the uses of these things and how these things are different or similar to each other, and how and when they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: The question is too general. Please ask about one specific technical issue, and add all the relevant technical details (i.e., your code and/or configuration). Do not ask us to teach you "everything there is" about some utility or topic. Those - you should study yourself using the relevant documentation online. In your question here, you are essentially asking others to copy/paste that documentation into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ganache and Truffle are developer tools. MetaMask is a browser wallet. Geth is software for running an Ethereum node. Does that answer all questions?

You might also want to have a look at https://soliditydeveloper.com/solidity-overview-2020/.